# With a Rust derive proc_macro, can you check if the struct derives another trait?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros, derive

Say I want to my derive trait `Builder`. This creates another type `FooBuilder`. FooBuilder should implement `Debug` iff `Foo` also derives `Debug`.

```
#[derive(Debug, Builder)]
struct Foo {
    bar: String
}

fn main() {
   println!("{:?}", Foo::builder(); // Returns the type `FooBuilder`, works
}
```

```
#[derive(Builder)]
struct Foo {
    bar: String
}

fn main() {
   println!("{:?}", Foo::builder(); // Doesn't work, because Foo doesn't derive Debug
                                    // so FooBuilder doesn't derive Debug
}
```

I was trying to check the `syn::DeriveInput { attrs, ... }` but couldn't find the derive statements in there.

Comment: No. The only thing you can see from the proc macro is the input tokens.

Comment: I thought this might be possible by having the macro emit `where Foo: Debug` on the `impl Debug for FooBuilder`, but this only works with a [nightly compiler feature](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a767e11ec3ff53e73e4d9dbfde569d83) (see the [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48214), where you may be able to find workarounds in the comments).